# Activity processor on emails - doesn't work if sent to BCC recipients?

Tags: civimail

I send an email from my Gmail account to say 200 recipients and because I don't want their addresses to be public, I BCC them

I also BCC my Activity processor account.

In Civi, the Activity processor account record appears but none of the other 200 recipients.  I'm guessing this is because they were BCC?

If I don't BCC them, they appear on the relevant Civi record.

Is this an error or by design?

Comment: Are you mass mailing through CiviMail or sending an email through the actions on the search result screen?  Also, what version of Civi and CMS are you using?

Comment: Allen.. neither .. I want to send emails from outside of Civi, without the names being visible to recipients and have the email recorded as an activity on the recipients contact record.   Using Civi to send these types of emails isn't in practical terms an option due to the adhoc nature of the recipients lists

Answer (score 5):

Neither error or design but by the simple fact that the BCC addresses will never be seen by CiviCRM.

Activity Processor relies upon receiving an email sent to it containing the relevant information.  As you are sending using BCC, the 200 or so email addresses will never appear in the email.

You should send the email from inside CiviCRM and then you will get the result you want.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, makes sense now I think about it..  sadly sending via Civi for these sorts of ad hoc emails just isnt practical.. I think Ive found a way to do it using mail merge for gmail and including a BCC for each individual recipient..

Answer (score 3):

If you're regularly sending something to 200 people BCCed in Gmail, you're just asking for trouble--not just in getting the information into CiviCRM, but also for getting flagged as a spammer.

You must be getting the emails from somewhere--either they're in some list of yours already (which means you ought to use CiviCRM for keeping that list) or you received them from someone else (which means you ought to import them into CiviCRM with a tag or group).

Although it means a change in your workflow, the bulk BCC from Gmail is an unsustainable solution.  Using CiviCRM more deeply should help dodge spam problems, and it'll make activity recording automatic.